# OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget in android

Tags: android-widget

i am facing a problem of OutOfMemoryError that is bitmap size exceeds vm budget .When I load image in listView  ,First 10 image load proper but we click next button for next 10 images  .This error  **OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget in android**

How can i resolve this problem, any one please solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the next 10 images do you delete the first 10 to free up the memory? Otherwise you're program needs more and more memory until it's up. Is this an android app you might want to make the images smaller so it doesn't consume so many memory.

Comment: Please use this method  hopping Vm error resoled              public void onLowMemory() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onLowMemory();
  imageLoader.clearCache();
  drawableManager.mCache.clear();
  System.gc();
 }

Answer (score 0):

Please use this " android:largeHeap="true" in application Tag  of  your app's Manifiest.xml file.

Your OutOfMemoryError issue May be solve out.